# How to group elements with the same name in an array list?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make an inventory system for a discord bot. Is it possible to "Stack" elements with the same name in an array list? For example:
`(2) Item 1`
instead of
`Item 1`
`Item 1`

```js
data.findOne({
    userID: message.author.id
    }, (err, data) => {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        {
            let itemList = data.items.slice(0).join("\n")
            let invEmbed = {
                title: `${message.author.username}'s Inventory`,
                description: `${itemList}`,
                color: 5762047
            }
            return message.channel.send({embed: invEmbed})
        }   
    })
```

Comment: You could try storing the item in an object {"amount": 2, "item": "itemxxx"} and before you add an iitem to the itemList you have to check if the amount is greater 1. If it is edit the String before adding it to the itemList

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to convert the array into an object of `item:count` values:

```js
{
  'Item 1': 1,
  'Item 2': 3,
  'Item 3': 1,
}
```

And then use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to convert the object *back* into an array:

```js
[['Item 1', 1], ['Item 2', 3], ['Item 3', 1]]
```

Which we can then [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to our desired format.

```js
const array = ["plum", "peach", "apple", "pear", "apple", "plum", "plum"];

const counted = Object.entries(
  array.reduce((acc, fruit) => ((acc[fruit] = (acc[fruit] || 0) + 1), acc), {})
).map(([fruit, count]) => (count > 1 ? `(${count}) ` : '') + fruit);

console.log(counted);
```

Comment: You can also change `(count > 1 ? \`(${count}) \` : '') + fruit` to just `\`(${count}) ${fruit}\`` if you'd like the numbers to appear for all items, not just the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do this.

```
const items = ['item1', 'item1', 'item2', 'item2', 'item3'];
let final = [];
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    let counter = 0;

    for (let s = 0; s < items.length; s++) {
        if(items[i] === items[s]) counter++;
    }
    final.push(`(${counter}) ${items[i]}`)
    final = final.filter((x, i) => i === final.indexOf(x));
}

console.log(final)
```

The output provided from the above code is:

`[ '(2) item1', '(2) item2', '(1) item3' ]`